# JavaScript array flatten with an if statment

Tags: javascript

flatten two array with an if statment
I have array1 and array2 
I want array3

```
<script>
    var array1 = [[5,10],[6,10],[7,10],[8,10],[9,10]];
    var array2 = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,10],[4,10],[5,40],[6,40]];

    // only the second number will add if they are different
    // [5,10] + [5,40] 
    // [6,10] + [6,40]

    // array3 = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,10],[4,10],[5,50],[6,50],[7,10],[8,10],[9,10]];

</script>
```

Comment: Step 1: Use a better structure (for example a Map). Step 2: it's now trivial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: Where's the effort? Did you even attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a proposal with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in a single loop and a temporary object.

```js
var array1 = [[5, 10], [6, 10], [7, 10], [8, 10], [9, 10]],
    array2 = [[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 40], [6, 40]],
    array3 = [];

array2.concat(array1).forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a[0]]) {
        this[a[0]] = [a[0], a[1]];
        array3.push(this[a[0]]);
        return;
    }
    if (this[a[0]][1] !== a[1]) {
        this[a[0]][1] += a[1];
    }
}, Object.create(null));


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Solution with `for` loop

```js
var array1 = [[5, 10], [6, 10], [7, 10], [8, 10], [9, 10]],
    array2 = [[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 40], [6, 40]],
    array3 = [],
    i, 
    temp = Object.create(null),
    array = array2.concat(array1);

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!temp[array[i][0]]) {
        temp[array[i][0]] = [array[i][0], array[i][1]];
        array3.push(temp[array[i][0]]);
        continue;
    }
    if (temp[array[i][0]][1] !== array[i][1]) {
        temp[array[i][0]][1] += array[i][1];
    }
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: how can i handle this with for in vanilla js

Comment: @MohammadGheydari, please see edit.